# How to get tile image data with Openlayers 3

Tags: cordova, openlayers-3

Is there a way, how to get loaded tile image data - let's say XYZ layer will be used with OSM data source? I would like to save them for later off-line usage in my mobile application, but I don't want to use natively cached data as I need full control over the files.

Answer (score 0):

So you need something like Mapserver or Geoserver to serve your offline tiles.

You can start from [this guide](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Rendering-OSM-data-on-Ubuntu-12.04) or [from this](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/).

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for - I need the data to be handled on a device, note remotely. As OL3 can store the images in cache and read it back I do believe, there is a way, hot to get access from my application.